# Using php variable inside raw query laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am trying to get the difference between two dates in Laravel. So i have tried below code.

Laravel Query:

```
 $currentdate = Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Vancouver');

 $assigned = DB::table('p_n_rs')->leftjoin('library_updates', 
 'p_n_rs.Request_ID', '=','library_updates.Request_ID')
 ->select('p_n_rs.*','library_updates.Completed_Date', 
 DB::raw('datediff(slaEndDate,$currentdate) as remdays'))
 ->get();
```

But the result value for `remdays` is always null. I have also used concatenation operator and seperated php variable and query but still `remdays` column is null. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: to pass the value of $currentdate to the query use as : `DB::raw('datediff(slaEndDate, '$currentdate ') as remdays'))`

Answer (score 0):

Bind Parameter in DB::raw() like this

```
 $currentdate = Carbon\Carbon::now()->setTimezone('America/Vancouver');

 $assigned = DB::table('p_n_rs')->leftjoin('library_updates','p_n_rs.Request_ID', '=','library_updates.Request_ID')
 ->select('p_n_rs.*','library_updates.Completed_Date', 
 DB::raw('datediff(slaEndDate,?) as remdays',[$currentdate]))
 ->get();
```